# Get number of frames in a video via AVFoundation

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I'm trying to find the number of frames in a video I've just opened, without decoding all the frames.

I open with `AVAsset` and then get an `AVAssetTrack` for the video. What next ?

Answer (score 10):

You could do this:

```
float durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
float framesPerSecond = assetTrack.nominalFrameRate;
float numberOfFrames = durationInSeconds * framesPerSecond;
```

Comment: You are assuming that the video has a fixed frame rate. AVFoundation doesn't make that assumption.

Comment: Well, it depends on where your file is coming from. If you are capturing it yourself you can set max and min rates to be the same. Same idea for an AVAssetWriter. Constant frame wouldn't be an assumption anymore. AVAsset only holds a pointer to a video file. It doesn't go through the whole thing counting frames before playing it. Hence an exact number of frames is not something you can just read  off of a property. Probably why nobody replied to this question in a year and a half :)

Answer (score 5):

One relatively expensive way to do this is to use an AVAssetReader to read all the frames and count them as you go.

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let assetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first!
let assetReader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: self)
let assetReaderOutputSettings = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
]
let assetReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: assetTrack, outputSettings: assetReaderOutputSettings)
assetReaderOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
assetReader.addOutput(assetReaderOutput)
assetReader.startReading()

var frameCount = 0
var sample: CMSampleBufferRef? = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()

while (sample != nil) {
    frameCount++
    sample = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
}

// now you have frame count
print(frameCount)
```

Answer (score 5):

This has been updated to **Swift 4.2** and converted into an extension of `URL`.

```
import AVFoundation

extension URL {
    var videoFrameCount: Int? {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: self)
        guard let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
            return nil
        }

        var assetReader: AVAssetReader?
        do {
            assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }

        let assetReaderOutputSettings = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
        ]
        let assetReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: assetTrack,
                                                         outputSettings: assetReaderOutputSettings)
        assetReaderOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
        assetReader?.add(assetReaderOutput)
        assetReader?.startReading()

        var frameCount = 0
        var sample: CMSampleBuffer? = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()

        while (sample != nil) {
            frameCount += 1
            sample = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
        }

        return frameCount
    }
}
```

If it is able to convert the `URL` into an `AVAsset` of type `video`, it will proceed. Otherwise, a value of `nil` is returned.

Next, an `AVAssetReader` is created. Should this step fail, it will again return `nil`.

Since everything has been set up properly, it will now proceed to parse the output and count the frames. As long as a `sample` is produced, the loop will continue the frame count is incremented. Once no more samples are produced, it will terminate the loop and return the value for `frameCount`.

Answer (score 2):

Although the solutions that use `AVAssetReader` + `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` are correct, I recommend to create `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` with `nil` output settings. So that `AVAssetReader` doesn't decompress the frames and you get the result much faster.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
int getNumberOfFrames(NSURL *url)
{
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

    AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *readerVideoTrackOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:nil];

    AVAssetReader *assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:nil];
    [assetReader addOutput:readerVideoTrackOutput];

    [assetReader startReading];

    int nframes = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        CMSampleBufferRef buffer = [readerVideoTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(buffer);
        CMMediaType mediaType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType(formatDescription);
        if (mediaType == kCMMediaType_Video)
        {
            nframes++;
        }

        CFRelease(buffer);
    }

    return nframes;
}
```